# How to set style for pandas datetime column when exporting to excel?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code to set the column style:

```
    column_format = self.workbook.add_format({'border': 1, 'align': 'center'})
    worksheet.set_column(column_name, column.get("width", 20), column_format)
```

the style work well but the date time columns.

I think that it is because pandas has her own style for datetime column, and when i export to excel it is override mind.

i tried to set style in pandas itself -

```
tab_df_styler = tab_df.style.apply(lambda x: 
                                   ['border-width: 1px; border-style:solid; border-color: black' for v in x])
```

but then it is getting worse, it is override all the excel style. the align for example.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using worksheet.write_datetime:

```
    # fix datetime columns style
    series = data[column.get("field")]
    if pd.core.dtypes.common.is_datetime_or_timedelta_dtype(series):
        column_format.num_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'
        for row_index, value in enumerate(pd.to_datetime(data[column.get("field")])):
            if not pd.isnull(value):
                worksheet.write_datetime(row_index + start_row - 1, column_index - 1, value, column_format)
```